# jmeter how to add chromedriver extension in chrome profile

Tags: webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am doing

```
WDS.AddExtension(Path.GetFullPath("Ghostery_v5.4.1.crx"));
```

I know its wrong Please let me know in jmeter how to add chromedriver extension in chrome profile

```
Stacktrace in jmeter
2015/01/27 12:03:52 INFO  - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: Current thread name: 'xxxxx1-1', has browser: 'ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (606ce1d4c34688e1062579fd676f16a7)'



2015/01/27 12:03:52 ERROR - com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function AddExtension in object com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverScriptable@3a0ee49f. (<Unknown source>#1) in <Unknown source> at line number 1 
xxxx
```

Comment: what `ide` do you use?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to work with `JMeter` and `webdriver` but in `webdriver` it is fairly as simple as

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddExtension("something.crx");
```